# How to submit a tag with Bootstrap Tags Input plugin with space key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a form with a field that is using the [Bootstrap Tags Input plugin](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/). This plugin inputs a tag once the user clicks the **Enter** key.

Can anyone help use the documentation of the plugin to **input a tag once the user puts a "," (comma) or a space in the field?**

Here is the documentation - http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

2020 edit: heres the doco: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the `confirmKeys` parameter. From the documentation the default is to only have keycode for enter (13), but you can add the code for comma (44) and space (32) like this:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
    confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
});
```

Comment: how to allow the tags containing comma

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com You have enough rep to know that you should be asking another question, not posting a comment on another answer.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com Not at all, this question is how to submit tags with space, you want to know how to type tags containing a comma right?

Comment: comma is 44 , they use the ASCII printable
characters ; http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/comma-ascii-code-44.html

Comment: Is there any way to restrict confirm key to only semicolon and not coma , enter or any other key? I noticed even if i add some other key, coma and enter still works.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed Then remove 44 (comma) and 13 (enter) from the code above.

Comment: @DavidG  confirmKeys: [32] comma and enter still works with this.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed Then you need to file a bug with the person who maintains the library.

Comment: Yes i have created an issue there, No body replies :D

Comment: @SubhanAhmed Well you only created it 18 hours ago. This is an open source project and the devs don't get paid. You need to wait or submit your own pull request to fix it.

Comment: It doesn't function for me also, so it's either a bug or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `confirmKeys` to work. No error, it just made no difference to operation.

My root problem was that enter was submitting the form instead of creating the tag.

This issue solved it for me:

https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/625

Code reproduced here:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').keydown(function (event) {
    debugger;
    if ( event.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
})
```

If the field recieves enter, it removes and returns focus.

return false stops the enter key event bubbling up to the form.

With regards to using space, you should be able to use `event.which == 32` but that doesn't function for some reason.

EDIT:

After this I noticed that even when I removed the code, enter worked as required

Then I noticed the `cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty` option. So I guess my original form just wasn't set up properly

Answer (score 0):

The custom confirmKeys didn't work for me as it always works with enter and comma. My solution allows you to enter words separated by spaces and then hit enter to generate the tags:

```
$(control).on('itemAdded', function (event) {
    let items = event.item.split(' ');           

    if (items.length > 1) {
        $(control).tagsinput('remove', event.item, { preventPost: true });
        items.map(function (item, i) {              
            $(control).tagsinput('add', item);
        });
    }
});
```