# Stackoverflow style input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I guess everyone knows the tags stackoverflow is using when you're asking a question. After you press a space bar a certain style applies to anything you type.

My question is how to change the value typed inside an input to a tag like button exactly the way stackoverflow is using.

**1. Type a word** *(or pick it from jquery autocomplete which im using already)*

**2. Press space bar and the word changes to a tag** *(or appears as a tag immediately in case u pick it from the autocomplete)*

Is there any plugin to achieve this. Or any copy/paste code. But with the space bar part included... which is really important to me.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Look for **Select2**, **FCBKComplete**, **Chosen** and other autocomplete plugins.

Comment: Ive read some answers here which do not include the space bar part. I have seen the tokenizer plugins. But none have the space bar working in their demos.

Comment: Select2 and Bootstrap tags would be the answer if not commented! Cool ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does stackoverflow make its Tag input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839570/how-does-stackoverflow-make-its-tag-input-field)

Comment: This question's answers are far inferior to the original question [How does stackoverflow make its Tag input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839570/how-does-stackoverflow-make-its-tag-input-field) which for some reason is difficult to find when googling. (This question seems to come up more easily in google and ddg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out Bootstrap's Tag Inputs. When you hit "enter or a "," (comma), the styles get applied.

Here's the demo: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples

To use the space bar instead of the default comma seperator, simply define it when you initialize it

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [32]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking on something like this
http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

To allow create tag after space bar you can refer to this
[How to submit a tag with Bootstrap Tags Input plugin with space key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554629/how-to-submit-a-tag-with-bootstrap-tags-input-plugin-with-space-key)